# Whitelist firebase analytics& google analytics

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I have a basic question I have **adaway** app installed in my device but I want to test firebase analytics in my phone

Which domains I have to whitelist to unblock the **adaway** blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist the following endpoint in order to collect Analytics data for Firebase powered app.

***https://app-measurement.com/a***

Make use of the inbuilt Debug Tools for testing provided by Firebase.